# Can a sniffer find out a password of an FTP server

Tags: security, passwords, ftp, windows-networking

My company is working with an FTP server. In order to login to this server, a simple username/password is needed.

As I heard that FTP is not very safe, I decided to launch a very simple test:

Using Ethereal as a sniffer tool, I captured all outgoing/incoming network messages while launching a simple `dir` command on the FTP server.

Filtering the capture result on the FTP server's IP address, I was astonished to see my username and password in readable format in that result.

My fear is that a hacker who manages to install a sniffer on FTP server side, might be capable to capture usernames and passwords and hence, sabotage our business.

My network responsible however (to whom I have communicated my results) starts asking questions about local logins version domain users, although in my opinion those things are not related to this issue.

Am I right, and is it correct that a hacker, using a sniffer, might capture usernames/passwords or does Windows networking indeed have a solution for this?

Comment: A password sent to an insecure connection to a FTP server is sent in plain text.  You should use a secure connection like SFTP instead.  Of course as pointed out, once infected with malware, even a secure connection can be compromised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a hacker manages to install **anything** on your server, you have much bigger issues than leaked password...

That being said, FTP is indeed a very insecure protocol, and you should probably have a look at [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), which simply put is an SSL-encrypted version of FTP.

Comment: Ok, my formulation might indeed be better: I realise that normally a hacker can't install anything on the FTP server, but I also know that the FTP server is accessible through regular internet. I have no idea how they do it, but I believe that hackers might have the ability to install a sniffer on a router, used for the communication towards the FTP server. Would this possibly reveal the username/password, as I fear?

Comment: Well, yes.. The only way to be (moderately) safe is to encrypt the traffic, same thing with using HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: @Dominique Another situation where someone could capture the password would be someone sniffing traffic on an open wireless network (if the client was at a hotel, coffee shop, etc). BTW, I'd recommend switching from FTP to something more modern (like an HTTPS-based system) rather than just encrypting it with FTPS -- security is just one of FTP's problems.